# validation_split argument differences

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Due to the [*Train a Keras model*](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/fit.html) documentation there is a `validation_split` argument in the `fit` method to set apart validation data. Now one can use the [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/) object in the `fit` method which itself holds a `validation_split` argument. Now I am confused which parameter to set if I want to have say 20% of my data as validation data. Additionally: What happens if I only set any one of them solely or both together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the documentation for model.fit is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) The documentation clearly states the parameter `validation_split` is not supported when x is a dataset, generator or keras.utils.Sequence instance. So if you are using the ImageDataGenerator to provide the data you can not specify `validation_split` in `model.fit`.